# Como puedo conectar MySql de Xampp en QT6.2.3?

Tags: mysql, xampp, qt

Mi duda va por lo siguiente,
estoy desarrollando un programa en QtCreator en el que la conexión a la base de datos es fundamental para su funcionamiento.

Para ello lo que entendí es que había que instalar el driver de mysql para que el Qt lo detecte y funcione. Vi muchos videos de como se hace y todos son de versiones anteriores pero encontré este https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qeErME39zvw&t=315s en él se explica que poniendo unos archivos en unas de las carpetas en la carpeta raíz de Qt este driver se activa, así que si bien es de qt5, en el foro que lo encontré la persona en cuestión que compartió el video, también compartió un enlace de [GitHub](https://github.com/thecodemonkey86/qt_mysql_driver/releases) con las versiones nuevas de los archivos que se utilizan en el video. Así que intenté seguir el video, pero al ser una versión nueva, la estructuras de los archivos de github también era distinta.

Para no alargarme más, resulta que el qt lo detectó pero me soltó este mensaje al ejecutar mi programa:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como pueden ver, el software detecta que está el driver pero no lo carga.
Eh ahí el dilema, como puedo hacer que lo cargue?

A continuación unas imágenes de los archivos y las carpetas en las que tenía que ponerlos:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y por último dejo una foto del extracto de código donde hago la conexión y una foto del panel de control del xampp:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: Xampp]

De antemano muchas Gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Encontré la solución,
además de poner los archivos que se ven en las imágenes en esas carpetas como dice el video, para instalar el driver
simplemente debía ir a la carpeta del build de mi proyecto y poner el contenido de la carpeta release en la carpeta release de mi proyecto y con la de debug hacer lo mismo, y entonces ahí funcionó.